# How to move a bunch of bones exactly to the cursor with a single click operation

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I'm trying to find a solution to a problem. I want to move a bunch of bones to the cursor and I did "selection to cursor",but as you can see on the attached video,the bones were placed on the cursor higgledy-piggledy. I would like that they are placed exactly in the way that you see towards the end of the video,but without moving them with the `g` key,because in this way they aren't placed exactly where the cursor is located....

[video](https://sendvid.com/x60uoqvj)

Comment: This behaviour is a bit weird indeed. You could create a new bone and snap it to cursor the way you did, and it should be positioned right. After that the snapping tool (snap to vertice) should work on that new bone. But its not an elegant solution I admit

Comment: This question is now, in the fashion of a true link only question, completely unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this set all the child bones (finger bones) to have the connected option ON [image]

After that select their parent bone (wrist) and then snap selected to cursor as you did, this should move the parent bone with all its child bones together.